# DirectX11: Drawing multiple objects

Tags: c++, directx11, transformation, index-buffer, draw-order

How can I draw many different objects on screen at once, with multiple vertex buffers, using `DrawIndexed()`? (Drawing the same object is simple, and I'm not looking to instance)

...but I am looking to transform two different vertex buffers. (Yes I am using indexed vertices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind [multiple vertex buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at once. However, unless you use instancing or similar (passing transform data in a constant buffer, for example, which becomes cumbersome beyond a certain number of objects and which is effectively the same as instancing anyway), all the buffers bound at a given draw call share the same bound transformation.

In other words, your options are:

- use instancing (which you have discarded for some unspecified reason)
- use constant buffers to emulate instancing (which may also be off the table for the above)
- make multiple draw calls, one for each buffer into which you were able to pack all the objects that can share a transform
- pre-transform all your objects on the CPU, write their final world-space vertices into the buffer, and draw that (somewhat silly)

Comment: I didn't want to instance because the _content_ of each vertex buffer was different. 

It was something simpler than the draw calls. I'm unsure how to refer to individual (indexed) vertex data in the index buffer... If I need to of course... and also confuzzled about how to wrap the data in a class for transforms.

I thought about the cpu option, but my storage structures were in the heap and transforms would be called every single frame -or updated when changed... and it defeats the use of the GPU. :P

Answer (score 0):

Creating an `OBJECT` class did the trick. It allowed for object data separation and the member support I was looking for.